# Method of characteristics- $u=$ constant or $u = f(y)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Say $u(x,y)$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ and suppose we have the following pde -

$u_x - u_y = 0$

This equation has the following characteristics -

$\frac{dx}{1} = \frac{dy}{-1}$

$\frac{du}{dx} = 0$

Now I see in my notes that the second characteristic implies that $u = c$ with $c$ constant. However shouldn't this be $u= f(y)$...because $u$ is a function of both $x$ and $y$? I have seen this type of thing done in other information I've seen on the method of characteristics for pdes, so why are we allowed to say $u$ is just a constant instead of a function of $y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $u_x=u_y$, so if $u=f(y)$,  for some non constant function,  we have the left hand side is 0, but the right hand side is nonzero.   Hence $f(y)=c$ for some constant

Answer (score 1):

The second equation implies that $u$ is constant along the characteristics. From the first equation the characteristics are the lines $x+y=C$. Then $u$ is constant on those lines, that is, $u$ is a function of $x+y$.